# Generate Live Mp4 in UWP

Tags: c++, uwp

I want to develop a slide-show kind of app that could be casted to smart TV, similar to showing a PowerPoint slide show.  Standard Miracast solution via the *Connect* app does not work nicely since the phone resolution does not match the high resolution of the TV; not to count the fact that there is no way to hide the navigation bar with *TryEnterFullscreenAsync*. The images could be quickly rendered from vector sources. So my question is whether there is a way to generate MP4 on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can gerate the bitmaps on the fly, as you mentioned, then you can use FFmpeg to create the MP4.

Download ffmpeg source code and check the source of `doc/examples/muxing.c`
This example is pretty much doing this. Just replace the `fill_yuv_image()` by the actual thing you are rendering.

Don't forget to convert your pictures to YUV format. In this example, the encoder will need a YUV bitmap and you will probably render an RGB image. Google for `swscale` or even check the other examples from FFmpeg in order to solve this problem.

--

If you really want something Microsoft specific, then you must use the "Microsoft Media Foundation". There's a lot of samples here on how to encode and decode:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371827(v=vs.85).aspx

And you can use all these codecs:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819077(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking more for a Microsoft-provided solution instead of bundling an additional library. (I think that Microsoft did use ffmpeg or part of it in Windows.)